# How to use Agora's AI Noise Suppression for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora

I am trying to use Agora's Noise Suppression for Unity. But not sure what are the requirements for same and how to integrate for unity C#.

Things I have tried:
According to this https://www.agora.io/en/products/ai-noise-suppression/. I use below code.

```
engine_ = createAgoraRtcEngine();  

engine_->enableAudio();  

engine_->setClientRole(CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER);  

engine_->setParameters("{\"che.audio.enable.nsng\":true}");  

engine_->setParameters("{\"che.audio.ns.mode\":2}");  

engine_->joinChannel(yourToken, yourChannelId, yourInfo, yourUid);
```

But this thing is not working.
Please help what to exactly for AI Noise Suppression to work.